# Updating repo from github

Tags: bash, repository, git, github

i have a local copy (clone) of a github repo on my machine, when yopu first run my bash script it creates some folders that are your settings. The thing is that i need a command that checks if this local copy is up to date with its github repo ignoring those custom made files (they are all not part of the repo, meaning that mayube just ignore all that are not from the repo), and if it is not up to date, then reclone it without deleting those files

Comment: I think all you have to do is be in the directory that you cloned and run `git pull origin master` for it to download any updates that may be there.

Comment: but i just want to check if there are updates first yk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `cd` into the directory.

Then, run:

```
git remote update
```

Finally, run:

```
git status -uno
```

The output will tell you which branch you are currently on and if you are or not up to date.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278427) by user [@NeilMayhew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381619/neil-mayhew) for more detailed information.